# What is the meaning of ''cry oneself"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, transitivity, reflexive-pronouns

I came across this phrase/these words while reading a novel. What does it mean?
Like If I say :

> 1. I cried myself.
> 2. I wanted to cry myself.

Does it mean crying over oneself? I mean crying over something wrong one has done?

Here is the quote where I read it:

> A queer look came over John Arable's face. He seemed almost ready to cry himself.

*Chapter 1, Charlotte's Web*

Comment: Can you post more context, or link to the exact place where you read it?  It sounds wrong to this native US English speaker.

Comment: Was it just "cry oneself"? Not "cry oneself to sleep"?

Comment: @stangdon A queer look came over John Arable's face. He
seemed almost ready to cry himself.
Chap# 1: Page 3, Almost 6th paragraph
Novel : Charlottes Web

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Yes it was just Cry oneself.

Comment: @Khan See StoneyB below. This is just a plain old reflexive pronoun. The author might have provided a comma before _himself_ to make it clearer on the page, but this is a children's story, meant to be read aloud, and in English it is perfectly natural to say _"I was almost ready to cry myself!"_ with the meaning _"I, myself, was almost ready to cry!"_ My own children, at seven or eight years of age, had no trouble understanding this when I read it to them.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Actually it's an intensive pronoun. (I'm appreciating the irony of pointing that out to you)

Comment: @HarrisonPaine We can say either that it is an emphatic _use_ of the reflexive (as StoneyB points out below) or refer to it only as the "emphatic/intensive pronoun". I prefer to name fewer rather than more parts of speech, myself. :) The list is quite sufficiently long already.

Comment: Wait hang on.  It's been over 20 years since I last read/saw Charlotte's Web.  The family's last name is Arable?  They're farmers?  Do they own their farm?  If so, it's Arable land.  If that was intentional I suddenly have way more respect for E.B. White.

Comment: @Tofystedeth Mr White was not an author solely of children's books. He was one of the most brilliant humorists and essayists of his or any age. It was intentional.

Comment: As written and meant (!) by you the examples are simply wrong. A possble usage would be: 'I cry myself a river' or 'I cry myself to sleep'. Stoney exaplains the actual meaning of the quote.

Answer (score 20):

> He seemed almost ready to cry himself.

*Himself* here is not an argument of the verb; this is an emphatic use of the reflexive pronoun.

> John Arable **himself** seemed almost ready to cry.

It serves in particular to remind the reader of the context: John's daughter Fern is weeping because John intends to kill the piglet, and now John **too**, **even** John is close to tears. It is quite natural to place this at the end of the sentence, just as we often place *too* at the end: this shifts the vocal stress off of the verb onto the emphatic.

Comment: For want of a comma, a horse was lost...

Comment: I think _himself_ functions as an intensive pronoun in this construction.

Comment: Good answer, but honestly, I've never read any emphatic meaning into this, I just understand it to mean 'as well'. For instance, if my friend said to me, 'I'm hungry, can we go to a café?' I might reply, 'sure, actually, I wouldn't mind a bite to eat myself.' And I would certainly only mean to say 'I too', or 'I, like you, would like a bite to eat' and not 'I - yes I! - would like something to eat'

Comment: @Au101 *Emphatic* in the technical sense--that is, emphasizing the constituent it refers to rather than acting as an object of the verb. But putting it the end *does* put the strongest emphasis in the predicate on it--say it out loud and you'll find you're raising the pitch strongly on *self*.

Comment: @Au101 We use the terms _emphatic_ and _intensive_ as labels for the part of speech, not as descriptives. Every use of the _emphatic_ pronoun does not imply exclamation marks.

Comment: Sure, but I would definitely read '... and now John **too**, **even** John ...' as emphatic in the everyday sense of adding real emphasis to John. It's like you have it 'John Arable himself seemed almost ready to cry' - I would understand that use of 'himself' very differently to the usage in the OP. In the OP, I understand it purely to mean 'too' or 'as well'. 'I wanted to cry too/as well/like they who were crying'. The implication I see in the OP is that somebody was crying, and, actually, I wanted to cry too.

Comment: The correct technical description of this might well be 'emphatic' I more than trust you on that. I simply disagree that it's the same as 'John Arable himself seemed almost ready to cry.' To me, 'I wanted to cry myself' only indicates that I want to cry too. Whereas 'I myself wanted to cry' is highlighting/emphasising that I want to cry. I might even say, "The mood was subdued, I myself wanted to cry, but I didn't want to disturb the silence." Here nobody is crying. But I could only say 'I wanted to cry myself' if others were crying and I wanted to cry too

Comment: Well now I think about it, I could use 'I wanted to cry myself' if nobody else was crying, but in that case the tone of my voice would be different. And, well, I see these as two different senses, but I'll just tie myself up in knots if I keep talking!

Comment: @Au101 That's right. The subject ordinarily bears the least emphasis in the sentence, because it's "old information"; a reflexive right after it puts more emphasis on it, but it leaves the primary emphasis on the "new information" in the predicate; but putting the reflexive at the end moves the emphasis off the predicate and marks its referent, the subject, as the most highly emphasized constituent.

Answer (score 12):

The quote which caused confusion from *Charlotte's Web*:

> A queer look came over John Arable's face. He seemed almost ready to cry himself

Reading the story in full context, another character besides John Arable is already crying.  As things develop, John Arable gets more upset to the point where he himself may start crying.  This is a typical use of the intensive pronoun (himself/herself/itself/myself etc.).  A more concise, and complete example would be:

> Steve is eating ice cream. I am about to eat ice cream myself.

The intensive pronoun refers back to the subject (in the example **I** am the subject) and places extra emphasis on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

> I cried myself

is equivalent to

> I cried myself **(as well).**

Where "myself" indicates that some other person (--self) probably cried initially.

Another possible usage is to mean that person X responded by doing Y, but the speaker cried. That would typically be written better as

> **(Joanne was stunned.)** Myself, I cried.

There is an additional usage which is different;

> I cried myself **(silly | hoarse | to sleep)**

which is a way of saying the speaker cried till they were hoarse, etc.

Comment: The last example might be better as "to sleep". "I cried myself to death", while grammatical, is quite nonsensical/impossible.

Comment: :) edited 'to death' to 'to sleep', per Martha's suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> A queer look came over John Arable's face. He seemed almost ready to cry himself.

This is an oddly phrased way to say, "he was himself almost ready to cry."  To me it appears out of order, but I guess to the writer E.B White, this is perfectly natural vernacular.  "To cry oneself" might be a common expression in his experience.

Comment: Is there any other way to say this? Can we use "he was choked up or on verge of tears" here?

Comment: @Khan Yes, there are many ways to say this.  "Charlotte's Web" is a children's book and written in a kind of *folksy* vernacular.

Comment: Do you know where E.B. White's community was?

Comment: Apparently he was born near to and worked much of his life in New York City, but later lived in Maine.  So it's not clear why he would use that expression, since it doesn't sound like NYC to me.

Comment: What are the sentences preceding the ones you've provided?  If, in the preceding sentences, someone else was already crying, `He seemed almost ready to cry himself` is completely natural.

Comment: Interestingly enough E.B. White is one of the authors of "The Elements of Style".  I never made the connection before.

Comment: @andrew Yes, he was a decent writer when he was writing instead of telling other people how to write.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you are using it, it basically means "as well", so in your examples:

> 1. I cried **as well**.
> 2. I wanted to cry **as well**.

in other words someone else is already crying.

The other context as already mentioned is something additional like:

> I cried myself **to sleep**.

which basically "I cried until I went to sleep" or "I used crying to get to sleep", as you would use for "I rocked the baby to sleep".